# Sending statsD metrics with tags from python client

Tags: python, graphite, statsd, telegraf

I'm trying to send metrics to graphite from my python app through statsD,
I'm using [this client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/statsd) (which I understand is most common).

But I can't figure out how to send metrics with tags.

I've tried this syntax (from [here](https://www.influxdata.com/blog/getting-started-with-sending-statsd-metrics-to-telegraf-influxdb/)):

```
c.incr('foo.bar,tag1=val')
```

And also this (got the idea from [here](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tags.html#carbon)):

```
c.incr('foo.bar;tag1=val')
```

But nothing seem to work.

Did anyone succeeded sending statsd metrics from python with tags?

Thanks

Comment: Also tried `c.incr('foo.bar#tag1=val')` without success

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

It seems all you need to do now is to install:

pip install statsd-telegraf

See [here](https://github.com/Granitosaurus/statsd-telegraf)

Works as expected

---

To send tags from python statsD you need to install this fork:

https://pypi.org/project/statsd-telegraf/

But, two important notes:

1. Do NOT install from PyPI alone, it has an unfixed bug

```
    BAD: pip install statsd-tags
```

After installing from PyPI, Install directly from GitHub, using the correct username (In the PyPI link above, the wrong link is shown)

```
    GOOD: pip install statsd-tags
          pip install -e git+https://github.com/Granitosaurus/statsd-telegraf#egg=statsd-telegraf
```

2. The documentation in PyPI of how to use the tags is wrong.

Tags should be a dict. For example:

```
    import statsd
    c = statsd.StatsClient('localhost', 8125, prefix='foo')
    c.incr('bar', tags = {"key1": "value1", "key2":"value2"})
```

Comment: You don't need a special StatsD client. Telegraf's StatsD plugin/interface accepts tags by separating them from the name with a comma, like such: `servers.health.cpu,ip_address=111.111.111.111,server_name=pelican`

Answer (score -1):

It appears that there is no tag support in the python client as seen in [this issue](https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd/issues/83)

I looked for a different client that includes tags support but no luck.

I think the best option would be to take the code from [this rejected pull request.](https://github.com/jsocol/pystatsd/pull/105)